# VB.NET. ContexMenuStrip Subitems

Tags: vb.net

How to dynamically enable/disable contextmenustrip subitem in contextmenu_opening event. I managed to disable the item on contextmenustrip instead subitem.

thanks for your help!

Comment: There's probably an error in your *code*

Comment: I got the code now. tnx

Comment: For future reference: Share your code whenever possible.